# How to download PDF in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, controller

My method for download a `.pdf` file, stored in a bytes array object, directly, without storing it on disk, is not working.

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4.

```
public FileResult Convert()
{
    // read parameters from the webpage
    string url = "https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.Pdf/";

    // instantiate a html to pdf converter object
    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

    byte[] pdf = doc.Save();

    return File(pdf,System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "myfile.pdf");
}
```

Comment: In what way is this failing?  Perhaps the Mime Type is incorrect?  It looks like there's one specifically for PDF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mime.mediatypenames.application.pdf

Comment: Hi David, first of all, thank u for your comment, my borblem is that I can't have the download dialog, as well as the pdf file does not open in the browser.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by that.  Can you elaborate on the specific problem you're observing?

Comment: What I want is forcing the browser to show download dialog or openning the pdf file existing in the array bytes.

Comment: When you debug, what specifically happens here?  Is an exception thrown?  Is this action invoked at all?  What is the server's response?

Comment: when I run everything is fine, and the file is retrieved in return, but the only problem is that the download dialog box is not displayed in the browser, and that's my main goal.

Comment: From the server-side code, a `FileResult` (which is what you're returning) should do exactly that.  *However*, it's ultimately up to the browser what to do with the response.  Can you check your browser's debugging tools and take a look at the response headers that come with the file?  Specifically, is there a `Content-Disposition` header and what is its value?

Comment: Hello David, thank you for all.
For your advice to check the Content-Disposition header, the response of the server "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = Query.pdf" and therefore my method returns the desired pdf file.
Finally, I found the solution to peremettre the download of this file via the ajax, by attributing the event "window.location = this.url" to success.
Below is the ajax part used in my Index View.

Comment: $.blockUI({
message: '<h4 class="padding"><b>Demande en cours de génération...</b></h3><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw w3-margin-bottom"></i>',
css: {backgroundColor: '#dff0d8', border: '2px solid #A0C590',   }});
$.ajax({ 
url: 'Home/getPDF', 
 type: 'GET',
 data: { 'iddem': r1, 'dp': r2, 'dr': r3, 'nature': r4, 'duree': r5, 'etat': r6 }, contentType: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8', 
success: function (xhr) { 
window.location = this.url; $.unblockUI(); 
} });